# Date is not getting saved to mysql database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to save a date (user's birthday).

```
$values['name'] = $request->get('name');
$values['fbid'] = $request->get('fbid');
$values['birthdate'] = date("Y-m-d", $request->get('birthdate'));

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$user = new User();
$user->setName($values['name']);
$user->setFbId($values['fbid']);
$user->setBirthdate($values['birthdate']);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

This is however not working. I'm not seeing any errors. What could be wrong? When I delete the setter for the birthday, the user gets inserted into the database perfectly.

Edit:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $birthdate;

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param date $birthdate
 */
public function setBirthdate($birthdate)
{
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;
}
```

Comment: Could the setter be setBirthDate() instead of setBirthdate, also after setBirthdate you could try $user->save();

Comment: Make sure you data type is et properly in the DB and that you have enough place to store the data in your field.

Comment: It's definitely setBirthdate(). Just checked :) I've set the type in the entity with the annotation. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
$values['birthdate'] = date("Y-m-d", $request->get('birthdate'));
```

To

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$values['birthdate'] = $dateTime->setTimestamp($request->get('birthdate'));
```

Or look into how you can create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to pass to doctrine

Comment: I've tried this but then I get: Failed to parse time string (580946400) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character","class":"Exception" ...

Comment: What format is $request->get('birthdate') returning?  Try to var_dump it and see.

Comment: You need to convert the timestamp to a DateTime object.  See updated answer.